# I need help with selecting correct title for technical article

Tags: grammar, programming, technical, titles

I am a technical writer, tasked with producing a tutorial on PHP programming. In the latest work on the series, I've titled my article: 
"An Overview of PHP Data Types and Variable Concepts"

The editorial team is asking whether the title should be "...Variable Concepts" or "...Variables Concepts". Which title would be correct both technically and grammatically?

Note: There are multiple types of "data" and multiple types of "variables" in the PHP Programming language.

Comment: *Variable* here is a noun functioning as an adjective. [Adjectives do not inflect for number.](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=inflected+for+number)

Comment: If one of the strings  'variable concepts' or 'variables concepts' is in common use, use that. If both are, the choice of the singular attributive is generally the more common practice. If neither is, you can pick either, but 'variable concepts' might puzzle an intelligent layman more. /  This is not a question involving grammar. It's a style choice. 'Technically', one might choose the plural attributive as being more logical, but since when has English been logical? _Teethbrush_?

Comment: @Andrew Leach This has been covered on ELU before; increasingly many attributive nouns are being used in plural form. They function like adjectives in some respects. They don't become adjectives (some might like the restrictor 'central' here) (though I agree it's equally specious to say they're still nouns).  Like _ing_-forms, they're between extremes. There is gradience.

Comment: The specific problem here is that you don't want people to misunderstand and think you are going to talk about concepts that change depending on the circumstances.  Therefore I'm going to suggest *An Overview of PHP Data Types and Variables*.  Note, in isolation you could use *The Concept of a Variable*.